# InfluxDB 2.0 multiple aggregations

Tags: influxdb

I'm new to InfluxDB 2.0 and I used InfluxDB 1.6 for few months.
I'm trying to rewrite my queries to use flux language and I encountered problem with multiple aggregations.
Earlier I used this query:

```
select
  max(val_max) as val_max,
  min(val_min) as val_min,
  last(val_close) as val_close,
  first(val_open) as val_open
from candle
where time > '{t}' and interval = '{interval}'
group by currency_id
```

What would this query look like in flux?
I had similar query to rewrite before, that looked liked this:

```
select "
  max(last_price) as val_max,
  min(last_price) as val_min,
  first(last_price) as val_open,
  last(last_price) as val_close
from ticker
where time > '{t}'
group by currency_id
```

and after rewriting to flux it looks like this:

```
data = from(bucket: "{self.bucket}")
  |> range(start: {min_time})
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
      r._measurement == "ticker" and
      r._field == "last_price"
  )
  |> group(columns: ["currency_id"])
val_max = data
  |> max()
  |> set(key: "_field", value: "val_max")
val_min = data
  |> min()
  |> set(key: "_field", value: "val_min")
val_open = data
  |> first()
  |> set(key: "_field", value: "val_open")
val_close = data
  |> last()
  |> set(key: "_field", value: "val_close")
union(tables: [val_max, val_min, val_open, val_close])
  |> pivot(rowKey:["currency_id"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

The difference is that I use one column for aggregation in one query and multiple columns in another

Comment: How does your data looks in both of your methods ?

Comment: Where errors did you get?